# how to display the distance only 4 digits

Tags: php, formatting, floating-point

How can I make PHP display a floating point number with 4 digits after the decimal point?

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = sprintf('%.04f', $value);
```

or

```
$value = number_format($value, 4);
```